# xcode includes old ViewController with every new project

Tags: swift, xcode

I have run into a bizarre problem.  Don't know if it is pilot error on my part, or Apple's bug but it's strange.

If I try to create a new project (File/New..  Project) and choose "App" or "Game" or whatever... And no matter the destination of the project, when the project is created, the wizard has pulled the source for the ViewController from some old project of mine (involving SceneKit) that is no longer in existence.

Where is XCode getting this?  Why?  Mystery city.  Is it possible one can change the source for the ViewController and I somehow reset it?  Any other ideas?  Sounds like I might have to nuke XCode and re-install.  God knows XCode has a million bugs.

XCode 12.3  iOS 10.15.7

Comment: Weird. Have you tried the usual `Command` + `Shift` + `K` and quitting/restarting? Might need to reinstall it

Comment: Xcode does get its projects from internal templates. I would think that getting rid of the cache and the app might help.

Comment: Sadly, no.  I have tried all of these approaches and others.  Nothing works.  Nice bug, Apple.  I am going to resign myself to deleting XCode and re-installing.

Comment: OK, this is getting ridiculous.  I delete XCode, including DerivedData and everything else I could find that was XCode related. Ran the Dev tool for XCOde caches and cleaned out that way.  Reinstalled XCode and...  EXACTLY the same behaviour? WTF?  To be honest I don't know what to do next. Any suggestions would be welcome.  I can work around it, I supposed by just manually editing the wrong View code.  But I'll spelunk some more.